# Roslyn Analyzers with Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, visual-studio-2015, roslyn-code-analysis

We're using [SonarLint](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/) and [StyleCop](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) analyzers within Visual Studio 2015. These work great whilst developing, but was wondering if its possible to run these during a Jenkins build?

Ive seen SonarLint.Runner, so I'm assuming this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not closely familiar with Jenkins, but you could always install the analyzers into the project as NuGet packages and have them generate warnings and errors as a part of the MsBuild build:

1. Install the following 2 NuGet packages into the project you want to analyze: [SonarAnalyzer.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/) and [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/).

[image: Project with analyzers installed]

2. Optionally configure the severity of individual rules and treat warnings as errors if you want your build to fail in case of warnings.
3. Using MSBuild to compile a project configured like that will result in analyzers warnings and errors surfacing the same way as compiler errors and warnings. You should be able to treat them identically in Jenkins, as well:

   ```
   "D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
   (CoreCompile target) ->
     Class1.cs(13,17): warning CS0219: The variable 'a' is assigned but its value is never used [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(1,1): warning SA1652: Enable XML documentation output [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(1,1): warning SA1633: The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file. [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(13,23): warning SA1002: Semicolons must not be preceded by a space. [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(1,1): warning SA1200: Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(2,1): warning SA1200: Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(3,1): warning SA1200: Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(4,1): warning SA1200: Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(5,1): warning SA1200: Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(1,1): warning SA1652: Enable XML documentation output [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(1,1): warning SA1633: The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file. [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(5,77): warning SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(17,76): warning SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(18,74): warning SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(28,22): warning SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(32,84): warning SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(13,19): warning S1854: Remove this useless assignment to local variable "a". [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]
     Class1.cs(13,17): warning S1481: Remove this unused "a" local variable. [D:\Users\Damir\Temp\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers\SO_36412838_Analyzers.csproj]

       18 Warning(s)
       0 Error(s)
   ```

Comment: Thats exactly how I've set it up,  but running the build through the command line does not generate any warnings.

Comment: @ScottD: You're saying, you don't get the output as I've shown above? Did you check that the correct version of MsBuild is used? It should be 14.0 something, depending on the update installed.

Comment: I'll check the msbuild version, but i only get the warnings in Visual Studio.

Comment: This should work (and it's just what I'm doing to get build errors in Jenkins). You maybe missing `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` this in your config settings. I think it's required

Comment: Having tested this, my path to MSBuild points at the MSBuild in the Windows directory, not the one in Program Files. Running the one in the program files directory does include the roslyn analyzers.